# apt-get upgrade fails when "running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10..."

Tags: apt, python, 22.04

So I recently installed Ubunut 22.04.1 (dual boot with windows 10) and when running "apt-get upgrade" for the first time I get the following error that
I am not able to find a solution to anywhere.

```
E: py3compile:212: cannot create directory /usr/share/ibus-table/engine/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/ibus-table/engine/factory.py'error running python rtupdate hook ibus-table
```

am not sure if it's a bug or me missing something
I did apt-get update but it didn't help and here's the log

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  firmware-sof-signed gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libnfsidmap1 libudev1
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 linux-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 rsync
  ubiquity-casper udev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up python3 (3.10.6-1~22.04) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.10...
E: py3compile:212: cannot create directory /usr/share/ibus-table/engine/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/ibus-table/engine/factory.py'error running python rtupdate hook ibus-table
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-common:
 sssd-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-proxy:
 sssd-proxy depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-proxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distupgrade:
 python3-distupgrade depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-sss:
 python3-sss depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-sss depends on python3 (>= 3.10~)No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                      ; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-sss depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-sss (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netplan.io:
 netplan.io depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package netplan.io (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ipa:
 sssd-ipa depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                         however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-oauthlib:
 python3-oauthlib depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-oauthlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-software-properties:
 python3-software-properties depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-software-properties depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ad-common:
 sssd-ad-common depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yeNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                   t.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ad-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-krb5-common:
 sssd-krb5-common depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-krb5-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:22.04.14); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: eNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                     rror processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-krb5:
 sssd-krb5 depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.
 sssd-krb5 depends on sssd-krb5-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-krb5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-krb5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:22.04.14); however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:22.04.14); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-reNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                      lease-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-advantage-tools:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:
 python3-uno depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-uno depends on python3 (<< 3.11); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-uno depends on python3 (>= 3.10~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd:
 sssd depends on python3-sss (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package python3-sss is not configured yet.
 sssd depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.
 sssd depends on sssd-ipa (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-ipa is not configured yet.
 sssd depends on sssd-krb5 (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-krb5 is not configured yet.
 sssd depends on sssd-proxy (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-proxy is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-lib2to3:
 python3-lib2to3 depends on python3:any (>= 3.10.5-0~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-lib2to3 depends on python3:any (<< 3.12); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-lib2to3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ldap:
 sssd-ldap depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.
 sssd-ldap depends on sssd-krb5-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-krb5-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: error processing package sssd-ldap (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-mako:
 python3-mako depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-mako (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ad:
 sssd-ad depends on sssd-ad-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-ad-common is not configured yet.
 sssd-ad depends on sssd-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.
 sssd-ad depends on sssd-krb5-common (= 2.6.3-1ubuntu3.2); however:
  Package sssd-krb5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ad (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-jwt:
 python3-jwt depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-jwt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-speechd:
 python3-speechd depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-speechd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gdbm:amd64:
 python3-gdbm:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.10.5-0~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gdbm:amd64 depends on python3 (<< 3.12); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gdbm:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
 software-properties-gtk depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-gtk depends on python3-software-properties (= 0.99.22.3); however:
  Package python3-software-properties is not configured yet.
 software-properties-gtk depends on software-properties-common; however:
  Package software-properties-common is not configured yet.
 software-properties-gtk depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 sssd-common
 sssd-proxy
 python3-distupgrade
 python3-sss
 software-properties-common
 netplan.io
 sssd-ipa
 python3-oauthlib
 python3-software-properties
 sssd-ad-common
 sssd-krb5-common
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 gnome-shell
 sssd-krb5
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
 python3-uno
 sssd
 python3-lib2to3
 sssd-ldap
 python3-mako
 sssd-ad
 python3-jwt
 python3-speechd
 python3-gdbm:amd64
 software-properties-gtk
 gnome-menus
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
ls /usr/share/ibus-table/
data  icons  setup  tables
```

I would be really grateful if someone helps me with how to solve this error

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ibus-table`

Comment: Thank you very much! it solved the issue but now I still get ```The following packages have been kept back:
  firmware-sof-signed gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libnfsidmap1 libudev1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  linux-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 rsync ubiquity-casper udev
``` should I force upgrade them?

Comment: If you cannot figure out why packages are kept back, try the Search box. Or open a new question for your kept-back problem, which seems unrelated to the solved problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you boil out all the fluff, this is a simple missing-file problem.

The key lines of your output are:

```
E: py3compile:212: cannot create directory /usr/share/ibus-table/engine/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/ibus-table/engine/factory.py'error running python rtupdate hook ibus-table
```

So let's see which packages should be providing the file:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/ibus-table/engine
ibus-table: /usr/share/ibus-table/engine
```

Reinstalling the package `ibus-table` should install the missing files.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ibus-table
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, it helps alot !